# Multiple @ JS Comment bug in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, comments

I've come across a *bug/undocumented feature* in IE 7, 6.5 (perhaps others?).  This doesn't effect Opera (10.5x) Firefox (3.5.x) or likely any other browser (this is all I've tested so far).  It doesn't seem to be a documented ability of Javascript.

By including a comment denoted by double slashes, and directly followed by double at signs (`//@@`), the whole `.js` file is rendered useless.  I've checked several variations and here's what I've found (where fail=JS isn't loaded, pass=JS is loaded):

1. fail: `//@@`
2. fail: `//@ @`
3. fail: `//@@@` - any number of @ doesn't seem to make a difference
4. fail: `//@@ text` - any content following doesn't seem to help
5. fail: `//@hello@` - any content between @ doesn't seem to help
6. pass: `// @@`
7. pass: `// @ @` - space before first @ seems to prevent
8. pass: `//hello @@` - any content before first @ seems to prevent
9. pass: `/*@@*/` - only seems to apply to `//` comment style

IE 7 - just ignores the file, when trying to reference the content of that file you get an error along the lines of "`<function/object> is undefined`".  IE6.5 has the decency to report "`Invalid character`" which significantly improves your ability to find the problem!

And so the **question:** Does anyone know why this is happening and what's going on?
You can work with it (insert a space, use the other comment style etc) but it's worth noting the problem's there, since can be time-consuming to debug.

**UPDATE:**
How to reproduce:

*Source:* flaw.ie.html

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="turnon.cc.js"></script>
    <script src="flaw.ie.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    World
  </body>
</html>
```

*Source:* flaw.ie.js

```
//@@
alert('hello');
```

*Source:* turnon.cc.js

```
/*@cc_on
 @*/
```

*Result:*
IE: page:World
FF/Opera: Alert:Hello! page:World

*Potential conclusion:* Once conditional compilation is turned on in IE, be careful with comments that vaguely resemble the syntax.

Comment: Well Methodin has the root-cause, it doesn't look like there's a solution (short of not using libraries with conditional compile statements and avoiding them yourself, or being very careful with at signs and comments).  It definitely seems like a bug, but also short sited there's no /*cc_off*/ command (at least it's not documented/doesn't work in the IE versions I have to test)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely related to conditional comments:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/conditionalcompile.shtml

Comment: That looks promising - we're certainly finding a use for @ in comments in JS... however all examples (I can find) are show use in `/**/` comments (alone) and it's supposed to only operate after you've turned conditional compile on (`@cc_on`) - it's supposed to ignore them otherwise.  That's a pretty major flaw in their parsing algorithm if `/*@@*/` comments work but `//@@` don't.

Comment: Ah ha!  While writing out code to reproduce the issue (thanks @Dr.Molle), I discovered the use of the library `modernizer-1.5.min.js` (unmodified) was making a difference - low and behold, `/@cc_on` can be found in there (line 20, char 95) - so conditional comments seem to be the start of the problem - once they're on, don't use `//@@`.  Illogically `/*@@*/` is still ok.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce this, maybe it depends on your environment.

Take a look at this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323487/en
Maybe it's useful

Comment: It's uncompiled/uninterpretted code (.html file, with .css and .js includes).  [running through Apache for the record]  But that JScript .NET error for case #3 sounds suspiciously familiar - which would imply JScript.NET is being (incorrectly) used instead of Javascript (where @ has no meaning)