# IE9 javascript //@example syntax error

Tags: javascript, syntax, comments

in IE9
we have a syntax error.

```
var hash = {}; 
// @return
function func(){};
```

Why do we have a syntax error on line2 ?

Comment: The syntax error should be at the unnamed function statement, I think.

Comment: My bet is it does not relate to the comment... remove the comment and see it for yourself...

Comment: Hm ... in my version of IE9 this passes without errors.

Comment: I'd *guess* you are running into [conditional compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/121hztk3(v=vs.94).aspx). Avoid starting comments with the @ symbol.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple @ JS Comment bug in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894079/multiple-js-comment-bug-in-ie)